# send URL of assets-library to MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, alasset

I want to play movie from assets-library. I get a ALAsset from camera roll, then send its URL to MPMoviePlayerController:

```
xxxViewController *SelectVC = [[xxxViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: [[mediumAsset defaultRepresentation]url]];

- (id)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if (self)
    {
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];

        [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
        [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];

    }

    return self;
}
```

The error message as:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2012-07-23 19:11:54.194 [5466:907] url assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=DA201372-BC11-4C0A-B134-B7E89FBC7DAF&ext=mov
2012-07-23 19:11:54.286 [5466:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-07-23 19:11:54.289 [5466:907] Error (null) setting playback mode to 'AVAudioSessionModeDefault'
2012-07-23 19:11:54.313 [5466:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2012-07-23 19:11:54.340 [5466:907] [MPQueuePlayer] Inserting item <AVPlayerItem: 0x209eaae0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x209e8f20, URL = assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=DA201372-BC11-4C0A-B134-B7E89FBC7DAF&ext=mov>> into player <AVQueuePlayer: 0x20a65f90>
2012-07-23 19:11:54.408 [5466:907] [MPQueuePlayer] Items after insertion: (
    "<AVPlayerItem: 0x209eaae0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x209e8f20, URL = assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=DA201372-BC11-4C0A-B134-B7E89FBC7DAF&ext=mov>>"
)
2012-07-23 19:11:54.930 [5466:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2012-07-23 19:11:54.956 [5466:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not the error. I open the diagnostics in schemes, so all of log out and the speed of app become slow.